# ListView - ItemTemplate table styling

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to create an ItemTemplate using a 4x3 table. I want the first column to contain an image and the cells in the other columns info about the image. I am using the code below but the 1st row renders at the bottom of the image and the 2nd row below it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" cellpadding="2" id="tblBooks" style="">
          <tr runat="server">
              <td runat="server">
                  <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                      <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </td>
          </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                            <asp:NumericPagerField />
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                                ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
         <tr runat="server">
            <td rowspan="4">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~\\Static\\Images\\BookCovers\\{0}", Eval("CoverImageSmall")) %>' Height="120" Width="90"/>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size:large; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:10px; color:Black;">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TitleLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            </td>  
         </tr>
         <tr runat="server">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding-left:10px;">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FirstNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LastNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr runat="server">
            <td colspan="2" style="padding-left:10px;">
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr runat="server">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**EDIT:** To be more clear, the result I am after is like this:

```
______________________________________________
|               |___________Title_____________|
|    Image      |____________Name_____________|
|               |______Value_____|____Value___|
|_______________|______Value_____|____Value___|
```

But what I get is this:

```
______________________________________________
| _____________ |                             |
||   Image    | |                             |
||            | |                             |
||____________| |___________Title_____________|
|               |____________Name_____________|
|               |______Value_____|____Value___|
|_______________|______Value_____|____Value___|
```

The CSS is reset.

Comment: Have you tested this in other browsers? Same or different behavior?

Comment: In IE and Firefox they have the above mentioned behavior. In chrome however things get weirder... The title cell still appears in the same position but the Name cell appears above it (in the position I would expect it to be if everything worked fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rowspan automatically makes the column and all the other rows/cells will be added around it. You can remove all the colspans and the second td in the last row.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <tr runat="server">
        <td rowspan="4">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~\\Static\\Images\\BookCovers\\{0}", Eval("CoverImageSmall")) %>' Height="120" Width="90"/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:large; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:10px; color:Black;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="TitleLabel" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
        </td>  
     </tr>
     <tr runat="server">
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FirstNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LastNameLabel" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' />
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr runat="server">
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr runat="server">
        <td>
        </td>
     </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

UPDATE: Based on the supplied jsfiddle, it shows the issue is with the use of the vertical-align:baseline attribute applied by the reset css stylesheet. If that CSS attribute is removed, or is overridden for the title cell to something like vertical-align:bottom it displays as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/9HsvF/10/

Comment: Tried it but nothing changed. The top cell on the 2nd column still behaves as if it inherits the rowspan="4" from the first <td>

Comment: @Tsarl: Is http://jsfiddle.net/9HsvF/ not the expected behavior? The HTML is correct, if so. Perhaps it has to do with other CSS on the page, or what the labels are outputting? Can you provide more detailed code and/or output?

Comment: That's exactly what I am after but somethings seems to mess it up. Updated the question. I am not sure I understand what you mean by output though...

Comment: @Tsarl: The ASCII art version is helpful, thanks. By output I mean the final resulting HTML with all the assets and such. Your HTML snippet looks correct, so it is probably interactions with CSS rules, or something specific to what is in the 'title' cell that is making it so large. It's difficult to tell what it could be from just the HTML provided. Can you simplify the page as much as possible and put it in a jsfiddle where you can reproduce it?

Comment: @Tsarl: Oh, I see. It is because of the vertical-align on your CSS reset. See my edit above on how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't think I would ever find what was causing it if it weren't for you. Btw, it only works if I completely remove the vertical-align. Overriding it still creates problems...

Comment: @Tsarl: As long as you override the vertical-align on the TD cell (not the span) than it works. See the fiddle I posted — it has it set that way there.

Comment: My previous comment was based on your last fiddle. It displays the cells like it did at the beginning for some reason.

Comment: The problem is fixed (removed the vertical-align) in all browsers except Firefox.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question in case you are interested in helping again :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671772/listview-item-template-styling-cross-browser-differences

Answer (score 0):

I have write down a simple code: 
`<tr>`
  `<td>Image Code</td>`
  `<td colspan="2">Title</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
  `<td  rowspan="3"><td>`
  `<td colspan="2">Name</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
  `<td>Value1<td>`
  `<td>Value2</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
  `<td>Value1<td>`
  `<td>Value2</td>`
`</tr>` 
Try this with your code. Hope it will work as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I would like the image cell to have a rowspan="4". Your code gives a slightly different table format from the one I am aiming for.