# ListView - Item Template styling - Cross browser differences

Tags: asp.net, html, css, listviewitem

This is a follow up on my previous question ([ListView - ItemTemplate table styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631739/listview-itemtemplate-table-styling)). I am still trying to make the ItemTemplate look like this:

```
______________________________________________
|               |___________Title_____________|
|    Image      |____________Name_____________|
|               |______Value_____|____Value___|
|_______________|______Value_____|____Value___|
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Opera but there are problems in the other browsers.

Firefox:

```
______________________________________________
| _____________ |                             |
||   Image    | |                             |
||            | |                             |
||____________| |___________Title_____________|
|               |____________Name_____________|
|               |______Value_____|____Value___|
|_______________|______Value_____|____Value___|
```

IE:

```
______________________________________________
| _____________ |___________Title_____________|
||    Image    ||____________Name_____________|
||             ||______Value_____|____Value___|
||_____________||                |            |
|               |                |            |
|_______________|______Value_____|____Value___|
```

In Safari it displays like in IE plus it adds a HUGE gap above it.

Here is the output of the page and the CSS http://jsfiddle.net/9HsvF/21/ I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You better try to achieve the layout with `div`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Get rid of the tables if possible. And try a div layout. A layout template output can be like (http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/1/):

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div class="leftColumn">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/da748a4c6e9b4c97af37c32af7531544.jpg"/>
        </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        <div class="titleRow">Title</div>
        <div class="nameRow">Name</div>
        <div class="values">
            <div>value1</div><div>value2</div>
        </div>    
        <div class="values">
            <div>value3</div><div>value4</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.leftColumn
{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.rightColumn
{
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}
.titleRow,.nameRow
{
    text-align:center;
}
.values
{
    clear:both;
}
.values div
{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it with divs and fixed width on the rightColumn. It works fine in Opera. In firefox it adds a scroll bar on the right column even though it has smaller height than the left. In IE the divs show empty (no data at all). In chrome the right div appears below the left with plus it has scrollbar like in FF, same in Safari plus that HUGE gap above the first template.

Comment: Changed to overflow:hidden to remove the scrollbars.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V5aCa/5/ Like that it works in all browsers except IE. There is a problem with the overflow property of the container div. In IE all the divs are empty of data, if I change the overflow property the data shows up (the right div displays below the left though) and the format in all the other browsers gets messed up.

Comment: try adding `overflow:auto` to leftColumn and rightColumn class

Comment: I tried the code in your fiddle; it seems working fine in my IE :|